# Rotate words around vowels in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, stack

I am trying to write a program that reads the stdin stream looking for words (consecutive alphabetic characters) and for each word rotates it left to the first vowel (e.g. "friend" rotates to "iendfr") and writes this sequence out in place of the original word. All other characters are written to stdout unchanged.

So far, I have managed to reverse the letters, but have been unable to do much more. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STK_SIZE 256

char stk[MAX_STK_SIZE];
int tos = 0; // next available place to put char

void push(int c) {
    if (tos >= MAX_STK_SIZE) return;
    stk[tos++] = c;
}

void putStk() {
    while (tos >= 0) {
        putchar(stk[--tos]);
    }
}

int main (int charc, char * argv[]) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (isalpha(c) && (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c ==         'E' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u' || c == 'U')) {
            push(c);
        } else if (isalpha(c)) {
            push(c);
        } else {
            putStk();
            putchar(c);
        }
    } while (c != EOF);
}
```

-Soul

Comment: Lack of test for `c == EOF` before `} else { putStk(); putchar(c);` needs review.

Comment: First 2 if clauses both do `push()` - so any character is pushed, vowel or not - is that the plan?

Comment: You use a buffer instead of stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways your can approach the problem. You can use a stack, but that just adds handling the additional stack operations. You can use a mathematical reindexing, or you can use a copy and fill solution where you copy from the first vowel to a new string and then simply add the initial characters to the end of the string.

While you can read/write a character at a time, you are probably better served by creating the rotated string in a buffer to allow use of the string within your code. Regardless which method you use, you need to validate all string operations to prevent reading/writing beyond the end of your input and/or rotated strings. An example of a copy/fill approach to rotating to the first vowel in your input could be something like the following:

```
/* rotate 's' from first vowel with results to 'rs'. 
 * if 's' contains a vowel, 'rs' contains the rotated string, 
 * otherwise, 'rs' contais 's'. a pointer to 'rs' is returned
 * on success, NULL otherwise and 'rs' is an empty-string.
 */
char *rot2vowel (char *rs, const char *s, size_t max)
{
    if (!rs || !s || !max)  /* validate params */
        return NULL;

    char *p = strpbrk (s, "aeiou");
    size_t i, idx, len = strlen (s);

    if (len > max - 1) {    /* validate length */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insuffieient storage (len > max - 1).\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!p) {   /* if no vowel, copy s to rs, return rs */
        strcpy (rs, s);
        return rs;
    }

    idx = p - s;        /* set index offset    */
    strcpy (rs, p);     /* copy from 1st vowel */

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)   /* rotate beginning to end */
        rs[i+len-idx] = s[i];

    rs[len] = 0;        /* nul-terminate */

    return rs;
}
```

Above, `strpbrk` is used to return a pointer to the first occurrence of a vowel in string `'s'`. The function takes as parameters a pointer to a adequately sized string to hold the rotated string `'rs'`, the input string `'s'` and the allocated size of `'rs'` in `'max'`. The parameters are validated and `s` is checked for a vowel with `strpbrk` which returns a pointer to the first vowel in `s` (if it exists), `NULL` otherwise. The length is checked against `max` to insure adequate storage.

If no vowels are present, `s` is copied to `rs` and a pointer to `rs` returned, otherwise the pointer difference is used to set the offset index to the first vowel, the segment of the string from the first vowel-to-end is copied to `rs` and then the preceding characters are copied to the end of `rs` with the loop. `rs` is *nul-terminated* and a pointer is returned.

While I rarely recommend the use of `scanf` for input, (a `fgets` followed by `sscanf` or `strtok` is preferable), for purposes of a short example, it can be used to read individual strings from `stdin`. Note: responding to upper/lower case vowels is left to you. A short example setting the max word size to 32-chars (31-chars + the *nul-terminating* char) will work for all known words in the unabridged dictionary (longest word is 28-chars):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { BUFSZ = 32 };

char *rot2vowel (char *rs, const char *s, size_t max);

int main (void)
{
    char str[BUFSZ] = {0};
    char rstr[BUFSZ] = {0};

    while (scanf ("%s", str) == 1)
        printf (" %-8s => %s\n", str, rot2vowel (rstr, str, sizeof rstr));

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

(shamelessly borrowing the example strings from WeatherVane `:)`

```
$ echo "friend vwxyz aeiou" | ./bin/str_rot2vowel
 friend   => iendfr
 vwxyz    => vwxyz
 aeiou    => aeiou
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions. Note: you can call the `rot2vowel` function prior to the `printf` statement and print the results with `rstr`, but since the function returns a pointer to the string, it can be used directly in the `printf` statement. How you use it is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to write the whole program for you, but this example shows how to rotate a word from the first vowel (if any). The function `strcspn` returns the index of the first character matching any in the set passed, or the length of the string if no matches are found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vowelword(const char *word)
{
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    size_t index = strcspn(word, "aeiou");
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", word[(index + i) % len]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    vowelword("friend");
    vowelword("vwxyz");
    vowelword("aeiou");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
iendfr
vwxyz
aeiou
```

Comment: An alternative is `char *vowel = strpbrk (word, "aeiou");` and `size_t index = vowel - word;` It's basically '6-to-one', 'half-dozen-to-another'.